# I met my boss three years ago

Tags: grammar, tense, sentence-structure, past-simple, since

Could I answer in three ways like these:

1. It’s three three years since I met my boss.
2. It’s three years since I last met my boss.
3. It’s three years since I first met my boss.

I think the first and the second are somehow similar, but the third is not correct? Please explain to me.

Comment: I have combined your "answer" into the question where it should be. Please delete your "answer"

Comment: Note than an  American native English speaker would almost certainly say "It's been three years" instead of "It's three years".

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence can mean either 3 years have passed since you last met your boss, or you met your boss for the first time 3 years ago. It depends on context.

The second sentence means - you haven't met your boss for 3 years, but you may have met him several times prior to that (more than 3 years ago).

The third sentence means the opposite - you met your boss for the first time 3 years ago and [may] have met him many times since, but not before.

To avoid any ambiguity, maybe you should say either

> It has been 3 years since I last met my boss.

or

> I met my boss for the first time 3 years ago.

Comment: I am a native English speaker, and I would interpret 1 as being identical to 3, and 2 as being a special case. If you wanted a synonym for 2, I would suggest "It's been three years since I *saw* my boss".

Comment: @shadowtalker Now you mention it, I partially agree. I think the first sentence is actually ambiguous and I'm going to change my answer to reflect this.